# How to Pivot-and-Sort for two columns in python?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I have a super-large dataframe of customers, item categories and their price. I would like to do some initial investigations:

- Identify the top e.g n=5 customers based on their TOTAL spending.
- for each of those customer, identify the top categories that they spend.
- Then possibly make a plot on descending order showing the top customer
  with their name as X and their spending as Y. For each, how to show their shopping categories?

this would require to pivot and sort. This is a sample-data generator, thanks to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe?rq=1) .

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.core.defchararray import add

np.random.seed(42)
n = 20

cols = np.array(['cust', 'cat'])
arr1 = (np.random.randint(5, size=(n, 2)) // [2, 1]).astype(str)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    add(cols, arr1), columns=cols
).join(
    pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(n, 1).round(2)).add_prefix('val')
)
print(df)

df.pivot_table(index=['cust'],values=['val0'],aggfunc=[np.sum])

df.pivot_table(index=['cust','cat'],values=['val0'],aggfunc=[np.size,np.sum])

# the order according the previous line should be cust1,cust0,cust2. How to do? The following is the desired output in this case.

                size sum
                val0 val0
cust    cat
cust1   cat4    6.0  4.27
        cat3    2.0  1.07
        cat2    2.0  0.98
        cat0    2.0  0.44
        cat1    2.0  0.43

cust0   cat1    1.0  0.94
        cat4    1.0  0.91
        cat2    1.0  0.66
        cat3    1.0  0.03

cust2   cat1    2.0  1.25
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Comment: I am using pandas 0.23.4

Comment: Do you need plot bat? Or lines?

Comment: bar would be better, i can change it later when I get the first solution.

Comment: Edited answer, please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is better aggregate `sum` for avoid `MultiIndex` in columns.

First aggregate `sum`:

```
s = df.groupby('cust')['val0'].sum()
print (s)
cust
cust0    2.54
cust1    7.19
cust2    1.25
Name: val0, dtype: float64
```

Then get top values by [`Series.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html):

```
top5 = s.nlargest(5)
print (top5)
cust
cust1    7.19
cust0    2.54
cust2    1.25
Name: val0, dtype: float64
```

If necessary filter only top5 values by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df1 = df[df['cust'].isin(top5.index)].copy()
#print(df1)
```

For correct ordering `cust` create ordered categoricals and aggregate by both filtered columns, last sort by first level `cust` with column `size`:

```
df1['cust'] = pd.Categorical(df1['cust'], ordered=True, categories=top5.index)
df2 = (df1.groupby(['cust','cat'])['val0'].agg([np.size,np.sum])
         .sort_values(['cust','size'], ascending=[True, False])
         .reset_index())
print (df2)
    cust   cat  size   sum
0  cust1  cat4   6.0  4.27
1  cust1  cat0   2.0  0.44
2  cust1  cat1   2.0  0.43
3  cust1  cat2   2.0  0.98
4  cust1  cat3   2.0  1.07
5  cust0  cat1   1.0  0.94
6  cust0  cat2   1.0  0.66
7  cust0  cat3   1.0  0.03
8  cust0  cat4   1.0  0.91
9  cust2  cat1   2.0  1.25
```

Last pivot and plot by [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
df2.pivot('cust','cat','size').plot.bar()
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael , however you put by hand the order of categories which are here just 3. How to do automatically when we want e.g top n=100 customers?

Comment: @physiker - oops, give em some time

Comment: Fantastic @jezrael !! Highly appreciate your time and effort. BTW, I really like your profile code to reveal your email :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood the exact overview you want, but this is also possible by using `groupby` and then the `agg` method like the following:

```
overview = df.groupby('cust').agg({'val0':'sum',
                                   'cat':'max'}).reset_index().sort_values('val0', ascending=False)

    cust    val0    cat
1   cust1   7.19    cat4
0   cust0   2.54    cat4
2   cust2   1.25    cat1
```

So this aggregates on customer level and sums their total spending and shows the category which they spent on the most.

You dont have to use the `reset_index()` function, in that case it yields to the following:

```
overview = df.groupby('cust').agg({'val0':'sum',
                                   'cat':'max'}).sort_values('val0', ascending=False)


        val0    cat
cust        
cust1   7.19    cat4
cust0   2.54    cat4
cust2   1.25    cat1
```

And **finally** if you want the top 5 customers, you can simply use `.head(5)` since the values are already sorted descending:

```
overview = df.groupby('cust').agg({'val0':'sum',
                                   'cat':'max'}).sort_values('val0', ascending=False).head(5)
```

Comment: thanks @Erfan , please see my desired output in the question.